# Can I use one pandas table as a mapping table for another?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure how to do this. I have a table structured as following:

```
true_name   reference_name
abc         123
xyz         098
```

Another table with a column

```
true_name 
abc
abc
xyz
```

how can I use dataframe one to map all values in dataframe 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create key:value pair (dictionaty) of df1 columns using dict(zip()) and map over to df2.

```
df2['reference_name']=df2['true_name'].map(dict(zip(df1.true_name,df1.reference_name)))




    true_name  reference_name
0       abc             123
1       abc             123
2       xyz              98
```